# A Simple Database Backup for MySQL Database on diff host (computer)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Can someone please tell me how to do a Simple Database Backup for MySQL Database on diff host (computer).  I am trying to move my database from one host (server) to a new host (server)

Comment: have a look at the mysqldump command

Comment: I don't see how to pick a host.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: good question.. how can I find out

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

Comment: I would also consider this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989724/how-to-mysqldump-remote-db-from-local-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to transfer a database between servers, using phpMyAdmin, you can use `Export` on the database on the source to generate a .SQL script, and then use `Import` on the target server to transfer it.

Alternatively, if the database is too big, you could use something like [SQLDumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/).