# Execute mysqldump to back up database in sql format

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, mysql

I'm trying to use PHP's `exec()` function to run `mysqldump` to back up a database named `projectdata` from `Amazon Web Service`. But I can only create an empty sql file.

I'm running the php file with xampp, under Windows 7 where mysqldump is in C:\xampp\mysql\mysqldump

```
exec('C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump --user=user --password=password --host=cannotTellyou.amazonaws.com:3306 projectdata  > backup.sql');
```

Comment: you can able to post your [solution as a answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and mark it as correct answer.

Comment: If you run MySQL on a non-standard port like 5555, mysqldump can take `--port=5555` as a switch. MySQL dump may have worked if you specified `--port=3306`. Not providing a port allows mysqldump to assume 3306 default port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after removing the port number

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump --user=user --password=password --host=cannotTellyou.amazonaws.com projectdata  > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is: do a ssh login to your AWS machine. Run the mysqldump in command line and start debugging from there.

```
ssh <your remote AWS using your private_key>
```

then run

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p<password> yourDB | gzip > backupfilename.sql.tar.gz
```

use gzip if you want to zip your backup file, otherwise, it's not necessary.

Then refer to this post: 
[how to mysqldump remote db from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989724/how-to-mysqldump-remote-db-from-local-machine)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to explicitly specify the file name instead of redirecting the output. Like this:

```
exec('C:\xampp\mysql\mysqldump --user=user --password=password --host=cannotTellyou.amazonaws.com:3306 projectdata -r backup.sql');
```

The `-r` option should be used also because:

> Direct output to a given file. This option should be used in MSDOS, because it prevents new line '\n' from being converted to '\r\n' (carriage return + line feed).