# backuping Database Using Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, backup

I want to get the databse backup using mysql query.

If there is any query to get database backup in mysql?

Comment: Please always Google before asking. Asking trivial stuff like this on a Q&A site is tantamount to littering. It is trivial to find solutions by searching for `php mysql backup`

Comment: This question looks similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963624/mysqldump-on-remote-server). The first answer should answer your question, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like mysqldump?

Or u can just use export functionality in phpMyAdmin or smth like.

Lol, then just

```
mysqldump -uUSER_NAME -hHOST -p -B database1 database2 database3 > databases.sql
```

Then just enter the password and that's it. The dump is in databases.sql

Comment: yes like mysqldump.But i dnt know how to use it?

Comment: @Kichu then Google the manual. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it in your current scripts but just want to generate y backup once in a while with a GUI-based tool, use http://www.mysqldumper.de/

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, it largely depends on what you mean by 'backup'.

As others has mentioned, there are tools to dump the current database state as a script with a series of table definitions and inserts which you can feed then to mysql command line client or other tools allowing batch execution.

But, to be precise, these tools are not queries.

Nevertheless, there is `SHOW CREATE TABLE` query to pull the table definition.

There is [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html) query to backup table data to a local file, and its complement `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load the data back.